# Multiplying two sets of numbers in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, while-loop

I have two lists of numbers, say `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`, and I would like to form a new list which consists of the products of each member in the first list with each member in the second list.  In this case, there would be 5*5 = 25 elements in the new list.

I have been unable to do this so far with a while() loop.
This is what I have so far:

```
x = 0
y = 99
results = []
while x < 5:
    x = x + 1
    results.append(x*y)
while y < 11:
    y = y + 1
    results.append(x*y)
```

Comment: Could you post what you have so far?

Comment: By the way, how is the result 25 in this case?

Comment: I don't understand how you can get 25 from those list.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh He means elements in the resulting set.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh I was confused, too.

Comment: he means lists, not sets

Comment: @usethedeathstar I edited his post.

Comment: do you want us to explain it with a while loop? or do you want the most pythonic answer? (in one case you might want to understand the concept of a while-loop in python, in the other case you might want to learn python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wht dont you try with known old ways;

```
list1 = range(1, 100)
list2 = range(10, 50, 5)

new_values = []

for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        new_values.append(x*y)
```

Comment: Can you please explain this? Won't this give the same result as my while look (It will only multiply all x values with a single y value)

Comment: No, It will grab the first `x` and multiply it with all `y` values. Then grab the second `x` and multiply that will all `y` values etc...

Comment: So basically, the outer loop will run once and then the inner loop will keep on running until it's finished?

Comment: No, Outer loop will start its first run and it will consume all `list2` values. Then `list1` will grab its second value and consume all `list2` values (again). Then `list1` will grab its third value etc until `list1` all used up.

Comment: That's what I meant :P

Answer (score 9):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)  to generate all possible 2-tuples, then calculate the product of that:

```
[x * y for (x, y) in itertools.product([1,2,3,4,5], [7,8,9,10,11])]
```

Comment: But that will not work if I have to multiply more numbers (like all numbers between 1 and 1000?)

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal What do you mean by that?  This will definitely work for any two lists...

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal If you say you want all numbers between 1 and 1000, do you mean without duplicates or with duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is an example of an [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). The answer already posted with `itertools.product` is the way I would do this as well.

But here's an alternative with numpy, which is usually more efficient than working in pure python for crunching numeric data.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> x2 = np.array([7,8,9,10,11])
>>> np.outer(x1,x2)
array([[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [14, 16, 18, 20, 22],
       [21, 24, 27, 30, 33],
       [28, 32, 36, 40, 44],
       [35, 40, 45, 50, 55]])
>>> np.ravel(np.outer(x1,x2))
array([ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 28, 32,
       36, 40, 44, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55])
```

Comment: or instead of outer, you could do x1[:,None]*x2[None,:] (i guess this is more general since its easy to expand to x1*x2*x3*..., while i guess np.outer doesnt work with more than 2 arguments (correct me if im wrong on that one?)

Comment: Would be interesting to let the `timeit` module benachmark this vs. the other proposed solutions. Unfortunately I don't have `numpy` here to do it myself.

Comment: I think the comprehension will be faster for this small example, and numpy will overtake it for big data

Answer (score 1):

Without any importing, you can do:

```
[x * y for x in range(1, 6) for y in range(7, 12)]
```

or alternatively:

```
[[x * y for x in range(1, 6)] for y in range(7, 12)]
```

To split out the different multiples, but it depends which order you want the results in.

Comment: Eeek, nested list (in-)comprehensions! %-}

Comment: Easily comprehensible in this case, since the loops commute

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial

mult = lambda x, y: x * y

l1 = [2,3,4,5,5]
l2 = [5,3,23,4,4]

results = []

for n in l1:
    results.extend( map( partial(mult, n) , l2) )

print results
```