# How to get the cartesian product between sets in python without using loops?

Tags: python

This is my python code:

```
A={1,2,3}
B={4,5,6}
products = [{A,B} for A in A for B in B]
```

Is it possible to do it without using loops?

Comment: Look at itertools.product

Comment: @DanielMesejo still uses loops internally... dang!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with **itertools** `product` , `map` and `set`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A={1,2,3}
>>> B={4,5,6}
>>> list(map(set, product(A, B)))
[{1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}]
```

Comment: I needed a cartesian product(like {1,4}, {1,5} etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using **itertools**, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352776/multiplying-two-sets-of-numbers-in-python) (duplicate?)

```
[x * y for (x, y) in itertools.product(A, B)]
```